# MIPS architecture 'syscall' instruction

Tags: mips, system-calls, mips32, mips64

What is the role of syscall instruction in MIPS?

Answer (score 14):

The *syscall* is used to request a service from the kernel. For MIPS, the service number/code must be passed in $v0 and arguments are passed in a few of the other designated registers. For example, to print we might do:

```
li $v0, 1
add $a0, $t0, $zero
syscall
```

In this case, 1 is the service code for print integer. The second instruction effectively performs a copy from $t0 to $a0 which is the designated register where the argument is held ( in this case, the integer to be printed ). A list of the services and corresponding arguments is given in *[SYSCALL functions available in MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/Mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html)*.

Comment: What happens if the syscall instruction is used when the current program is already in kernel-mode? Does MIPS have any other modes besides user-mode and kernel-mode?

Comment: The MARS/SPIM set of system calls isn't fundamental to the MIPS ISA, it's just a set of simplistic "toy" system calls that a couple emulators choose to provide.  Linux on MIPS provides POSIX and Linux-specific system calls, and none of then convert integers to/from text; that's what libc *functions* are for.  The MARS/SPIM system calls provide a very limited subset of the functionality of scanf and printf (with a different ABI), among other things.

Answer (score 8):

It becomes a lot more obvious when you step outside the context of an emulator like [MARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM#SPIM_Alternatives/Competitors) or [SPIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM) where the system calls are somewhat artificial. On a real MIPS machine, you would use it transfer control the kernel to invoke a specific function.

For example, this is a basic *Hello, World!* program in MIPS 32-bit assembly for a Linux machine (I'm 95% sure this was on a mipsel install, though not that it matters much for this question):

```
# CS341L Fall 2008
# Lab Exercise #1
# Matthew J. Barrick <barrick@cs.unm.edu>

#include <asm/regdef.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

.data
    hello:  .asciz    "Hello World\n"
    length: .word    12
.text
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    li      a0, 1
    la      a1, hello
    lw      a2, length
    li      v0, SYS_write
    syscall
    move    v0, zero
    jr      ra
    .end    main
```

This corresponds very closely to the C code (if you have trouble following the MIPS assembly).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* hello = "Hello, World\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, hello, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

First note that headers are included to give the registers symbolic names (*asm/regdef.h*) and a header that will pull in symbolic names for the system calls (*sys/syscall.h*), so we don't have to refer to the system calls by number. The conventions for making a system call here are pretty much the same as calling a function, load the *a#* register with arguments, and then we load which system call we want into $v0 and invoke *syscall*. *SYS_write* corresponds to the basic *[write(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)* function for Linux/Unix (1 being standard output).

```c
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

So we're telling the kernel to write to the file handle 1 (standard output), the string *Hello*, using length bytes. On Linux you can see [syscalls(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) for all the different system calls available, but they pretty much correspond the core functions that the kernel provides and that (g)[libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) either wraps or builds upon for C/C++ programs.

Linux (and most Unix-like systems, going back to the [4BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4.4BSD#4BSD) route) have a function syscall(2) which is effectively the same thing.

Once you start doing more complex stuff, you'll either find yourself wrapping the *syscall* invoking into handy functions, or better yet just calling the corresponding libc versions (surprisingly easy to do, but another discussion).